# Bash: How to check in array check if input was entered twice?

Tags: bash

The array variable ARRAY_ITEMS adding input from the user.
Here my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$(echo -e "Adding $INPUT to array.")

while true; do 

    printf "\n
    A   B   C\n"

    echo -e "This is the array: $ARRAY_ITEMS: "
    read -p "Input: " INPUT

    case "$INPUT" in 
       A) echo $var1 ; ARRAY_ITEMS+=$INPUT ;;   
       B) echo $var1 ; ARRAY_ITEMS+=$INPUT ;; 
       C) echo $var1 ; ARRAY_ITEMS+=$INPUT ;; 
     *) echo -e "Whoopsy! Invalid input." ;;
    esac
done
```

The Output looks like this:
**A B   C This is the array: ABCAAABCAAA:

Input: D Whoopsy! Invalid input.**

How does my script have to look like so that the following output appears for an input that has already been entered?

**A  B  C
This is the array: ABC:
Input: A
ERROR. A is already selected.**

Comment: while it looks like you want to work with an array, your code (and the output you've provided) shows that you're not working with an array but rather a variable (`ARRAY_ITEM`) that contains a string of characters; it's not clear (to me) if you really need an array or just a string; your comment to chepner seems to indicate that you also want to manage the order of the inputs ... doable but requires a different coding method if deailing with array of values vs a string of values so, again, we need clarification from you as to what you really want ... array or string?

Comment: it may help us to know if you plan on doing anything else with your inputs later in the script and if so then *exactly* how do you plan to use them as this could also determine which is best ... array of values or a string of values

Comment: As others have said before: your `ARRAY_ITEMS` is not an array at all. It would be `ARRAY_ITEMS+=( "$INPUT" )` if you were actually appending things to an array (and `"${ARRAY_ITEMS[@]}"` to expand it). Also, note that all-caps names are used by variables meaningful to the shell and operating system; you should be choosing names with at least one character for your own variables to avoid unintentional conflicts. (`for PATH in */` is a classic example of breaking your script by a badly-chosen name when `for path in */` would be fine).

Comment: ...relevant POSIX standard document re: the variable convention is https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html; note the last sentence of the fourth paragraph: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities*; read it keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any preexisting like-named environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Here is an example of what I want to do.
Listing of various files in a directory, example 1: FILE_A, 2: FILE_B etc. The user enters a number to select a file or several files, example: 1 [Enter] followed by a new entry "2". All input from the user should be displayed like in my script: "This is the array: 12...".
My goal is that if a number (or the file that was listed) is entered twice, an error message appears so that this number or entry or file cannot be selected twice.

Comment: That sounds to me like you want two arrays: One listing the files (indexed by number, which a standard array is by default), one listing the items that were previously selected (which you can index either by name or by number per your preference, but where that index existing is how you tell that a value was already used)

Comment: Try running `files=( *.txt ); declare -p files` in a directory that has at least one .txt file; you'll see something like `files=( [0]='a.txt' [1]='b.txt' [2]='c.txt' )`, so you get numbers assigned to your regular array elements "for free"

Comment: And then if you initialize `selected=( )` and later set, say, `selected[2]=1` to say that the user picked 2 (aka `c.txt`), you can check `[[ ${selected[2]} ]]` to see whether c.txt was picked before.

Comment: Mind, your comment on a deleted answer by chepner implies that you care about ordering; it might make sense to have two separate arrays then -- one in order where the values are the selections, one with undefined order where the keys are the selections. The important thing is that key lookup is amortized constant time (it's basically the same speed no matter how big the array is), whereas searching values is O(n) -- it gets slower the longer your list is.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Unfortunately, I can't reconstruct the code using your tips. May I ask you to write down the script so I can better understand what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Between chepner's deleted and active answers, I don't think I have enough that's new/different to add to justify writing a full answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern-matching to see if the input is already in the string.

```
items=

while true; do 

    printf "\n
    A   B   C\n"

    echo "This is the array: $items"
    read -p "Input: " input

    case "$INPUT" in 
       A|B|C) if [[ $items = *$input* ]]; then
                echo "Error, $input is already in $items"
              else
                items+=$input
              fi ;;
       *) echo "Whoopsy! Invalid input." ;;
    esac
done
```

If the input could be something more than a single letter, you'll need to use an array and resign yourself to walking the array, one element at a time, to compare them to the input. Something like

```
items=()


while true; do
    ...
    found=0
    case $input in
        A|B|C) for x in "${items[@]}"; do
                 if [[ $x == $input ]]; then
                   echo "Error, already used $input"
                   found=1
                   break
                 fi
               done
               ;;
        *) echo "Error, invalid input" ;;
     esac
     (( found )) || items+=("$input")
 done
```

Comment: Slower if doing this with more than a trivially small number of inputs than it would be to use an associative array for a reverse index, no? (...but then, I now note a deleted answer such that you had that thought first as well)

Comment: Yeah, (for those who can't see the deleted answer) the OP indicated they wanted to preserve the order of the values.